# OutOfMemoryError while renaming multipartFile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to rename a mutipartFile before uploading it.

I used `MockMultipartFile` to rename it but an `OutOfMemoryError` occurs because it 's a large file and `MockMultipartFile` loads `multipartFile.getBytes()`.

Is there another solution?

My code is :

```
multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(mf.getName(), "nomFichier", mf.getContentType(),mf.getBytes());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test maximum upload file size with MockMultipartFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667276/test-maximum-upload-file-size-with-mockmultipartfile)

Comment: You shouldn't be using `MockMultipartFile` as that is for testing only. The name is part of the form, just send another name.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with file uploads, especially big ones, files should be processed as **streams**, for example using MockMultipartFile.getInputStream(). The wrong way to do it is to inhale the whole thing into memory; as using the getBytes() method you described.

Comment: thanks for your response , the same problem when i used .getInputStream()